# "Out of Memory" error with mechanize

Tags: python, memory, urllib2, mechanize

I was trying to scrape some information from a website page by page, basically here's what I did:

```
import mechanize
MechBrowser = mechanize.Browser()

Counter = 0

while Counter < 5000:
    Response = MechBrowser.open("http://example.com/page" + str(Counter))
    Html = Response.read()
    Response.close()

    OutputFile = open("Output.txt", "a")
    OutputFile.write(Html)
    OutputFile.close()

    Counter = Counter + 1
```

Well, the above codes ended up throwing out "Out of Memory" error and in task manager it shows that the script used up almost 1GB memory after several hours running... how come?!

Would anybody tell me what went wrong?

Comment: The first thing I'd try to rule out is that mechanize is leaking memory -- just use `urllib2.urlopen()` instead.

Comment: Just as a note, it's much more pythonic to do ``for counter in range(5000):``. And PEP8 recommends lower_case_with_underscores for variable names, while CamelCase is reserved for classes. Also, check out ``with`` for writing/reading to/from files.

Comment: (a) This sort of "what's up with my code" question is better on codereview (b) variable reuse as such is not the problem (c) Learn about memory profiling.

Comment: @Marcin No, code review is for *working* code, this clearly does *not* work as it throws an exception.  It is *off topic* for Code Review.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not exactly a memory leak, but rather an undocumented feature. Basically, `mechanize.Browser()` is collectively storing all browser history in memory as it goes.

If you add a call to `MechBrowser.clear_history()` after `Response.close()`, it should resolve the problem.