# Python, "Out of memory" error while working with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to run this program, but after awhile I am getting "Out of memory" error. Somehow I need to free some memory and I don't know how to do it in Python. Can anyone help me please?

Many Thanks in advance.

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

print('trying to login')
br.open('http://www.erepublik.com/en')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br["citizen_email"]="xxxxx"
br["citizen_password"]="xxxxx"
response = br.submit()
html = response.read()
if html.find('Logout') == -1:
    print 'username and password mismatch'
else:
    print 'logged in successfully'

for i in range(6395674, 1000000, -1):
    print('fetching %d' % i)
    usrlink = 'http://www.erepublik.com/en/citizen/profile/%d' % i
    try:
        response = br.open(usrlink)
    except:
        print 'User not found'
    html_user = response.read()
    response.close()
br.clear_history()
    if html_user.find('Press director') == -1:
        print "user doesn't have newspaper"
    else:
        npl = br.follow_link(url_regex='/en/newspaper/', nr=0)
        html_news = npl.read()
        pos = html_news.find('<em class="subscribers">')
        if pos == -1:
            print 'Something went wrong during extracting sub number'
        else:
            all_int = re.findall(r'\d+', html_news[pos:])
            sub_num = all_int[0]
            msglink = "http://www.erepublik.com/en/main/messages-compose/%d" % i
            br.open(msglink)
            br.select_form(nr=1)
            br["citizen_subject"]="xxxxx"
            br["citizen_message"]="xxxxx" % sub_num
            response2 = br.submit()
        html_res_mess = response2.read()
        response2.close()
        br.clear_history()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(6395674, 1000000, -1)` creates a gigantic list. For an iteration, you could better use `xrange(6395674, 1000000, -1)`, which creates a lazy iteration (where it will only generate the next number when it is actually needed). I think that might solve your memory problem too.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt answer. That shouldn't be a problem. It is just an iterator. I tested anyway and still memory getting bigger and bigger. The br.open() should be the problem. I try using br.close() but getting an error that said I am trying to close a NoneType!

Comment: Googling gave me this previous topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314149/out-of-memory-error-with-mechanize.

Comment: I saw it but that didn't solve my problem. I will change the above code.