# PYTHON - Itertools.combinations results in memory error

Tags: python, memory, combinations, python-itertools

I am creating a brute force script (for my studies) on python which connects to my login.php form and tries a combinaison of every characters of the alphabet to find the password.

The thing is that, after something like 110 000 combinaison, I am getting a memory error.

I already looked up on the net to find solutions which seems to be :

*--> gc.collect() & del var*

I tried to add the gc.collect() on the blank field of my function **bruteforce** so everytime i % 100 == 0, I clear the memory space but It dosen't work.

I can't find the way to add it in my script to free memory.

I think the problem is that I can't clear the memory space when my function is running. Maybe I should play with many threads like :

start 1
stop 1
clear space
start 2
stop 2
clear space
etc...

Do you guys have any suggestions ?

Here is my code :

```
import itertools, mechanize, threading, gc, os, psutil

charset='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

br=mechanize.Browser()

combi=itertools.combinations(charset, 2)

br.open('http://192.168.10.105/login.php')

def check_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss

def bruteforce():
    i = 0
    for x in combi:
        br.select_form(nr=0)
        br.form ['username'] = 'myusername'
        tried = br.form ['password'] = ''.join(x)
        i = i+1
        print "Checking : ", tried, " Number of try : ", i
        response=br.submit()
        if response.geturl()=="http://192.168.10.105/index.php":
            print("The password is : ", ''.join(x))
            break
        if i % 100 == 0:
            mem_before = check_memory():
            print "Memory before : ", mem_before

            print "Free memory "
            mem_after = check_memory()
            print "Memory after : ", mem_after


x = threading.Thread(target = bruteforce)
x.start()
```

Thank you !

Comment: There are only 325 combinations of 2 lowercase ASCII characters; how are you getting 110,000 iterations?

Comment: I doubt `combinations` is the problem; maybe there's a memory leak in the `mechanize` module?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant when I try with a bigger number than 2. Thanks for your answer, i'll take a look at mechanize.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chepner, I found that the issue was with mechanize, not with itertools.

A good way to fix it is by clearing the history : ["Out of Memory" error with mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314149/out-of-memory-error-with-mechanize)